# hibernate - why use hibernate if many of its options cant be used in production

Tags: java, sql, hibernate

I wrote classes for all the tables and did everything using hibernate , like applying constraints , giving column names, all the mappings using @ManyToOne and other mapping annotations etc.

But my Senior says, that I shouldn't do it, its useless and all these mappings are creating heavy queries, and that we should keep a separate DBScript for database operations.

Problem :
1) I don't understand what is the use of all the features of hibernate if you have to do everything using SQL only.  I am not even supposed to use hbm2ddl.auto option as update.

2) How to do mappings so that hibernate creates the best and most optimized queries. (basic idea behind how to do that.) or should I not use mappings and just keep foreign key variable type as the type of primary key of the other class.

Comment: you don't have to, those are choices made by your team lead.

Comment: basically it's the case of simplicity vs. performance. it's much easier to write jpa/hibernate code, but it takes much more time and memory to execute than plain jdbc.

Comment: so we should not use hibernate if we need good performance ??

Comment: when should we use hibernate ??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The main reason for choosing Hibernate is not performance. Hibernate is used to reduce the cost of development by allowing you to load and save your Java classes to the database without writing any database code. That is a big time saver, and therefore a big money-saver for whoever is paying you.

Hibernate may improve performance as it includes a cache, but I would not rely on it. Anyone who tries to tell you it is the answer to performance problems is selling something or has bought what someone else is saying. There are some cases where it might be faster (if the caching helps prevent repeated queries) and there are cases where it will be slower (if you are doing complicated queries or updates or in cases where Hibernate loads more data than you want).

As far things like foreign-key or unique key constraints: these can improve or hinder performance. An FK constraint may require validation on insert, but in some cases it may allow the query optimizer to produce a better query plan. It depends, and a discussion of all that is outside the scope of your question. You senior would really have to know what he is talking about to say definitely.

I would ask this:

Is database performance likely to be an issue on your system?

If it is not, then carry on using Hibernate and add all of the functional constraints that you like as they are probably going to ensure your program works, which is the most important thing.

If performance is likely to be an issue from the beginning, you really need to get a database expert to design your schema and your queries with performance in mind. This does not exclude using Hibernate, but you would have to consider how you create your Java classes more carefully as they will affect the queries generated by the ORM.

Answer (score 1):

The answer on question is in balance of performance, development cost and velocity, reliability and many other factors. For example, if you are developing application with direct sql queries mapping instead hibernate, you would received fast application, which reliability was based on jUnit tests (mainly) with poor code integrity (coherence), and you will heavy to work when some entities would be changed. On other hand, when you are using hibernate, you receive high speed and reliability development with good code integrity (which only increases with jUnit test), but cost of there is in non optimal queries to database, sometimes you will think that some data extraction would be more simple with sql then jpa\hibernate\hql. I saw hybrid variants, when for data extractions native sql used , but for data persisting hibernate used. After several years of balancing in such questions and factors, each new project we start with hibernate\jpa in architecture: cost is justified!